# rails 4.2 upgrade broke json rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried upgrading my rails app from rails 4.1.0 => 4.2.7 but found that it broke my JSON views. In particular, ActiveRecord objects no longer render correctly.

For instance: `Model.first.to_json` in rails console now produces `"#\u003cModel:0x007f9208c904e0\u003e"`, rather than valid JSON as before. `Model.first.as_json` works correctly, but for some reason, it seems `to_json` is calling `to_s` instead.

I tried overriding the ActiveSupport encoder but it didn't help, and am pretty stumped.
Any ideas?

(UPDATE: I also noticed `Time.now.utc.to_json` changed from `2017-12-07T19:38:47Z` => `2017-12-07 19:37:55 UTC`, the latter being == `time.as_json` and the former == `time.to_s`)

Comment: Where is the `.to_json` method's definition coming from? `Model.first.method(:to_json).source_location`

Comment: It's `nil`. does that mean it's in a native gem?

Comment: Not sure, but it should not be `nil`. I'd check your Gemfile for errant gems that may be overriding serialization.